# Equivalence of categories not preserving injectivity or surjectivity

Tags: category-theory

As far as I know, injectivity and surjectivity of a map are not categorical properties. Is example of equivalent (concrete) categories, for which these properties don't preserve known?

i.e. I am looking for categories $A,B$ s.t. the functors $F:A \rightarrow B$ and $G: B \rightarrow A$ give an equivalence of categories (i.e. $FG\cong 1_B$ and $GF\cong 1_A$) and some morphism $f$ in $A$ injective or surjective s.t. $F(f)$ is not injective or surjective.

Comment: I have edited your question. Is that what you mean?

Comment: If that is the case, the category of affine schemes and morphisms $\text{AffSch}$ and the category $\text{CRing}_1$ of commutative rings with unity and ring homomorphisms give an example.

Comment: G. Chiusole, not sure what you've meant by $ FG=Id_B $. It looks more like isomorphism of categories

Comment: Just a typo. My bad

Comment: Injectivity and surjectivity are not categorical properties, in the sense that they are not *defined* in arbitary categories. So your question does not make much sense.

Comment: @ArnaudD. They are defined in concrete categories, aren't they?

Comment: @G.Chiusole Is the category of affine schemes naturally concrete?

Comment: @CaptainLama To be honest I’m not sure. Quite possibly not. In my comment I assumed OP was referring to epimorphisms and monomorphisms.

Comment: @G.Chiusole, but epimorphisms and monomorphisms are always preserved under equivalence.

Comment: @Kumquat under covariant equivalence. Otherwise epis are sent to monks and vice versa. This is the case here. However, I see now that that is probably not an illuminating example for what you are looking for. Your first step would be to look for injections which are not mono and surjections which are not epi and then proceed. Those exist, but are not simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an minimal example satisfying both conditions at the same time, maybe not super interesting in itself but there we go.

Let $C$ and $D$ be two subcategories of the category of sets (so in particular they are concrete categories), defined by:

- the objects of $C$ are $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$, and the only morphisms are the identities, and the only map $\{1\}\to \{2\}$ (we do *not* take the map $\{2\}\to \{1\}$;
- the objects of $D$ are $\{1,2\}$ and $\{3,4\}$, and the only morphisms are the identities, and the constant map $\{1,2\}\to \{3,4\}$ with value $4$.

Then those two categories are equivalent (they are both equivalent to the abstract category $\bullet\to \bullet$), but the non-identity map in $C$, which is a bijection, is sent to the map in $D$ which is neither injective nor surjective.

Comment: They are even isomorphic.